# Muffle php_network_getaddresses on PDO connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

I'm trying to prepare a ZF2 application for production usage, and in preparing for worst case situations, one test is to trash all network connections.

Of course it explodes!  But am trying to make things quiet.  Here's the culprit:

Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php on line 281

Is there a toggle I can use to make PDO die quietly at a "global" level?  I did try these params:

```
'driver_options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'",
    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
 ),
```

Still a noisy death…

Thanks for your help

Comment: that's not really a pdo problem. it's pdo calling a mysql function, and THAT function's being noisy.

Comment: I did find this: `$this->resource->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection`